# Writing switch statements using integers

Tags: c#, switch-statement

```
if (intDaysOverdue <= 30)
{
            decInterestRate = 0m;
}
else if (intDaysOverdue >= 30 && intDaysOverdue <= 59)
{
            decInterestRate = .5m;
}
else if (intDaysOverdue >= 60 && intDaysOverdue <= 89)
{
            decInterestRate = .10m;
}
else if (intDaysOverdue >= 90)
{
            decInterestRate = .15m;
}
```

I need to write this info using a `switch` statement, but can't seem to figure out how

Comment: I cannot think of a way to use `switch`-`case` here.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, are you *sure* that you need to write this as a switch statement?

Comment: You can't use a switch for this. Why do you "need" to?

Comment: if `if (intDaysOverdue <= 30)` were `if (intDaysOverdue < 30)` you could  use `switch(intDaysOverdue/30)  case 0: ... case1: ....`

Comment: Also, all of your `>=` comparisons are redundant (implied by the previous conditional).

Comment: @EZI, that is a nice workaround, although (directed towards OP), there is no reason to overcomplicated this and make it harder to understand this by doing what is suggested, just use `if` conditionals, that is what they were made for.

Comment: Are these really your conditions? Because the first two seem to overlap. Why check for equality in the second condition (`intDaysOverdue >= 30 && intDaysOverdue <= 59`) when the first one will always handle the `== 30` case?

Comment: Professor wrote in the instructions to use a switch. unless it was a typo

Comment: @Cyral Why? isn't this readable?  `decInterestRate = (intDaysOverdue /30) * .5m;`

Comment: @EZI, That is, not what you suggested before. (What I meant was the if statements got the point across much easier, you don't have to think, "What does this do?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with a `switch`, but you can simplify it to:

```
if (intDaysOverdue <= 30)
    decInterestRate = 0m;
else if (intDaysOverdue <= 59)
    decInterestRate = .5m;
else if (intDaysOverdue <= 89)
    decInterestRate = .10m;
else 
    decInterestRate = .15m;
```

Your `>= 30` and `>= 60` conditions are not needed, as they are already true because of the prior if statements.

Switch/Case is more suited for specific values, not ranges. This *is* what the `if` statement is for.

If your interest rate increases .5 for every 30 days, similar to as [@EZI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2345956/ezi) suggested in the comments, you could further simplify the code to:

```
decInterestRate = ((int)Math.Min(intDaysOverdue, 90) /30) * .5;
```

Comment: thank you. i've figured it out

Comment: @user4338480 No problem, if this helped, please mark it as the accepted answer by checking the check mark next to it.

Comment: Downvoters mind commenting?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use switch here (you can manipulate it with a default case but why do that?)
`switch` and `case` are meant to test individual values, your condition needs an `if` statement.